# How do I check if a session value is inexistent? Do I use isset() or do I use $_session["a"]==null

Tags: php, session-variables, isset

can session values be null if they are not set? or should I use isset all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this, all OK. For example:

- `empty($_SESSION['a'])` will return true if the value doesn't exist or is empty (empty array, zero, empty string, etc)
- `isset($_SESSION['a'])` will return true if the value exists
- `array_key_exists('a', $_SESSION)` will also return true if the value exists

You shouldn't just use `$_SESSION['a'] == null`, because if `a` does not exist in the `$_SESSION` array, you will receive a notice.

Comment: also note, `array_key_exists` will return true if the key was set to `null`, whereas `isset` will return false. [See the type comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using `isset()` is a safe way to make sure a session variable is set. Note: This will return true if the value is FALSE.